# Managing the default header files directories in Code::Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am having serious troubles to discover how to add another directory to the default Compiler Directories to be searched for when #including something with angle brackets.

I would like to know how to install whole new libraries too if possible.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean add to the default include-search directories just for the project you are working on, or for every project that uses the compiler is question?

Comment: well if possible i would like to know both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As weird as it seems but I am going to answer my own question as I found the answer myself, and I want to share this simple information with other people.

Well it is done like this:

1. go to Settings.
2. choose Compiler Options.
3. go to the ( Search Directories ) tab.
4. in the ( Compiler ) tab add the Directories you want to be searched automatically.

of course, this applies on a global level, if you want to make it for specific projects than replace the first option with ( build options ) of the project.

That's it, I know it's easy but it took me a while to find it out :)